# How to Manually Trigger Click Event on Scatter Point in React/Recharts.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recharts

Currently I am unable to trigger a manual mouse event on an individual data point within recharts. I have a scatter plot with data points linked to a separate, second rendering of the data on top of a model in three.js. When I hover over a data point on the model, I would like to be able to tirgger hover functionality for the corresponding point on the recharts scatterplot.

I have attempted to create refs on each scatter point, unsuccessfully.

```
class Chart extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          data: []
        }
        this.scatter = React.createRef();
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
        this.handleMouseOut = this.handleMouseOut.bind(this);
        this.mouseSimulation = this.mouseSimulation.bind(this);
    }

  componentDidMount(){
    const newData = [];
    data.forEach(function(item) {
        var a = item.geometry.coordinates[1] - (-10.679538);
        var b = item.geometry.coordinates[0] - (-76.267526);
        let distance_from_pit = Math.sqrt( a*a + b*b );
      newData.push(
        {x: item.geometry.coordinates[0],
        y: item.geometry.coordinates[1],
        id: item.properties.id,
        distance_from_pile: distance_from_pit,
        conc: item.properties.conc + Math.random()*1500},)
    })

    this.setState({
      data: newData
    })

    this.props.setGlobalState({
      handleDataInteract: this.handleClick,
      mouseSimulation: this.mouseSimulation
    })
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps){
    if (prevProps !== this.props) {
      if (this.props.globalState.data_point_id !== undefined){
        const chart = this.scatter.current;
        console.log('chart didupdate', chart.props.points)
        // const scatterPoints = chart.props.points;
        // scatterPoints.forEach(function(point) {
        //   point.click();
        // })
      }
    }
  }

  handleClick(e){
    if (e.payload !== undefined) {
        this.props.setGlobalState({data_point_id: e.payload.id})
    } else {
      this.props.setGlobalState({data_point_id: e.name})
    }
  }

  handleMouseOut(e){
    console.log('mouse out')
      this.props.setGlobalState({data_point_id: ''});
  }


  mouseSimulation(event, x, y){
    let simulatedEvent = document.createEvent('MouseEvent');
    simulatedEvent.initMouseEvent('mouseover', true, true, window, 1,
            x, y,
            x, y, false,
            false, false, false, 0/*left*/, null);

    document.dispatchEvent(simulatedEvent);
    console.log(event + " at " + x + ", " + y);

    this.handleClick(event);
  }

  render() {
    const data1 = Object.values(this.state.data);
    return (
      <div className="chart">
        <section
          className="sectionStyle item">
          <h1>Lead Concentration</h1>
          <div className="bar-charts">
              <ScatterChart
                width={600}
                height={900}
                margin={{
                  top: 15, right: 15, bottom: 15, left: 15,
                }}
                >
                <CartesianGrid stroke="#000" />
                <XAxis type="number" dataKey="distance_from_pile" name="distance from pile" unit="" stroke="#000" />
                <YAxis type="number" dataKey="conc" name="concentration" unit=" mg/kg" stroke="#000" />
                <Tooltip cursor={{ strokeDasharray: '3 3' }} />
                <Scatter ref={this.scatter} name="dataset" data={data1} fill='#000' onMouseOver={(e)=>this.handleClick(e)} onMouseLeave={()=>this.handleMouseOut()} />
            </ScatterChart>
            </div>
        </section>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default withGlobalState(Chart);
```

Would like to achieve manual hover functionality triggered from outside of the recharts scatter plot.

Comment: You mean you want to programmatically trigger the `Tooltip` of the corresponding point on the scatter plot as you hover over your `three.js` model?

Comment: Yes, exactly--would like to trigger the Tooltip of the corresponding point (and also change the color of the point that's highlighted).

Comment: tooltip has a `trigger="click"` option that does what you want

Comment: @dsldsl where would the prop `trigger` be passed into and where would it be set to `"click"` ?